# facebook follow button social plugin missing

Tags: facebook, facebook-social-plugins

There used to be a social plugin from FB for Follow button and it was working fine on my clients website earlier. But recently I've noticed that it doesn't load. So when I tried looking for the issue, it seems like FB has removed it. Is that the case? I could not find any documentation regarding removal of / changes to follow button social plugin.

When I [searched for follow button](https://developers.facebook.com/search/?q=plugins%20follow%20button) on developers.facebook.com it does show "[Follow Button - Social Plugins](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/follow-button/)" as first result but when I open the page it says the link may be broken or the page may have been removed.

Has anyone else faced this issue? Is there any way to get the earlier functionality of follow button?

Search result:
[image: Search result]

---

Page error:
[image: Page error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2017/11/07/changes-developer-offerings/:

> **Follow Button:** With multiple options to follow a person or a Page, the Follow button has become redundant. You can use the Like button plugin as an alternative, which provides the ability to subscribe to a public profile or a Facebook Page's public updates.

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I've been hunting for .. just switched to the Like button.